# Mi ion-menu no abre cuando visito una ruta por segunda vez

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Les explico mi caso de uso: Tengo 3 vistas: Home, Programa y Parte. En Programa visualizo el contenido de un Programa y listo sus niveles (la información la obtengo por `Params`). Tengo un `componente Card` para listar esos Niveles y aquí hago uso de `@Input()` y también desde este componente es donde abro el menú lateral de `ionic 6`.

En el menú lateral listo los Módulos y Partes de ese Nivel. Aquí tengo el problema, es que cuando elijo una Parte y me muevo a la vista Parte, en esta sección tengo un `Breadcrumb` para regresarme al programa en el que estaba, al hacer eso al parecer la información por `Params` no se ejecuta o no llega del todo porque al querer abrir el menú lateral ya no responde.

Al parecer tengo un problema con el tema de preservar la información, por lo que he notado el menú no responde porque según TypeScript no hay DATA y al no tenerla no puede mostrarme el menú lateral. Obviamente ya verifiqué esto con Console Log y la DATA si está ahí pero no sé si estoy solicitando la información en un cliclo de Vida erróneo.

Igual usé `ionViewDidEnter()` pero no me funcionó. También apliqué el `operador !` pero el problema persiste.

**Aquí mi componente principal Programa**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { UtilsService } from '../../services/FAST-TRACK-FRONTEND/utils.service';
import { HttpGenericService } from '../../services/myServices/http-generic.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-programa',
  templateUrl: './programa.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./programa.component.scss'],
})
export class ProgramaComponent implements OnInit {


  urlApiImg = environment.backend + '/uploads/';

  programa!: any;
  niveles!: any;


  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  //<!-- Constructor -->
  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  constructor(
    private _generic: HttpGenericService<any>,
    private utilsServices: UtilsService,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }




  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  //<!-- ngOnInit -->
  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  ngOnInit() {
    // this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
    //   let id = params['id'];
    //   this.getPrograma(id);
    // });
  }


  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let id = params['id'];
      this.getPrograma(id);
    });
  }



  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  //<!-- Get Proyecto -->
  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  getPrograma(id: any) {
    this._generic.getOne('/programas', id).subscribe(programa => {
      // this.utilsServices.loading();
      this.programa = programa;
      this.niveles = programa.niveles;
    });
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="contenido" >

  <div *ngIf="programa">
    <!-- Header -->
    <app-header2></app-header2>


    <!-- Contenedor Info | IMG y Descripción -->
    <div class="content-info">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>

          <!-- IMG -->
          <ion-col sizeXs="12" sizeSm="12" sizeMd="12" sizeLg="4">
            <ion-img [src]="urlApiImg + programa.portada"></ion-img>
          </ion-col>

          <!-- Titulo -->
          <ion-col sizeXs="12" sizeSm="12" sizeMd="12" sizeLg="8">
            <h3>{{programa.titulo}}</h3>
            <h3>Descripción</h3>
            <ion-text>{{programa.descripcion}}</ion-text>
            <h3>Objetivos</h3>
            <ion-text>{{programa.objetivos}}</ion-text>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </div>

    <!-- Niveles | Card Para Niveles -->
    <app-card-programa [items]="niveles"></app-card-programa>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Aquí mi componente Card**

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card-programa',
  templateUrl: './card-programa.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card-programa.component.scss']
})
export class CardProgramaComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() items: any;
  nivel!: any;
  index!: any;




  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  //<!-- Constructor -->
  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  constructor(
    private menuCtrl: MenuController,
  )
  {

  }




  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  //<!-- NgOnInit -->
  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }




  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  //<!-- Get Nivel -->
  //<!-- ============================================================== -->
  getNivel(item: any, index: any){
    this.nivel = item;
    this.index = index;
    console.log('niveles');
    console.log(this.nivel);
  }




  closeMenu() {
    this.menuCtrl.close(); // Cierra el menú
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Contenedor Grid -->
<div class="contenedor-grid">

  <!-- Card | Abren el Menú Lateral -->
  <ion-menu-button class="card" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" id="{{i}}" (click)="getNivel(item, i)">
    <div class="content-titulo">
      <h3>{{item.titulo}}</h3>
    </div>
  </ion-menu-button>
</div>




<!-- Menú Lateral -->
<ion-menu contentId="{{index}}" *ngIf="nivel">

  <!-- Header -->
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title class="ml-4">{{nivel!.titulo}}</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>


  <!-- Content -->
  <ion-content>

    <!-- Lista Acordeon Modulos -->
    <details class="details2" *ngFor="let modulo of nivel!.modulos">

      <!-- Titulo Modulos -->
      <summary class="summary-modulos">{{modulo!.titulo}} <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down  rotate2 mr-1"></i></summary>

      <!-- Lista Acordeon Partes -->
      <div class="details3">
        <a class="" *ngFor="let parte of modulo!.partes" [routerLink]="['/part', parte.id]" (click)="closeMenu()">{{parte!.titulo}}</a>
      </div>

    </details>

  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```